# Slide Puzzle Solver Using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, grid, path-finding, puzzle

I'm making a Sliding Puzzle Game in python but with multiple empty squares,
for example:

```
                            (solution)
[9] [1] [ ] [7]             [1] [2] [3] [4]
[ ] [3] [5] [ ]      ->     [5] [6] [7] [8]
[8] [4] [ ] [6]             [9] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [2] [ ]             [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

In each iteration you can move as many pieces as you want, **one** square, as long as there is an available square. For example:

```
                            (after one iteration)
[9] [1] [ ] [7]             [1] [ ] [7] [ ]
[ ] [3] [5] [ ]      ->     [9] [3] [5] [ ]
[8] [4] [ ] [6]             [ ] [8] [4] [6]
[ ] [ ] [2] [ ]             [ ] [2] [ ] [ ]
```

The goal is to find a general solution for any problem of this kind, with as few iterations as possible.

My curent method of solving this problem is pretty slow (a lot of iterations) in my opinion, so I would love to see someone else take a look at the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it allowed in one iteration that 4 cells that shared a corner rotate -- to take each other's place?

Comment: Yes, as long as they only move one square, and they do not overlap.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make sense of that. Can you edit your question and add it as an example there?

Comment: You really should edit your question and bring clarification, and show your work, include your "slow" solution, and explain why you consider it slow (compared to what?).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm to solve this problem.

Let's define a function f that takes as input a state of the board and gives as output the minimum number of iterations to solve it for this state.

You want to evaluate f on the board that you have.

For the first iteration, you have some choices. For each of this choices, you will have a new set of choices for the second iteration, and so on.

However, notice that the graph of choices is not a tree. Making a certain set of choices can led to the same state as making another set of choices. So, sub problems overlap. This implies that you can use a dynamic programming approach (reusing solutions that were already evaluated for a sub problem). But you need to be careful with situations that cause infinite loop. It happens whenever you see a state that was already saw but is not yet evaluated. You can prune the graph at these nodes (just ignore them).

If this procedure ends without finding a solution, it's because there is no solution. If there is a solution, it will find it.

Let me know if you have difficult to implement this algorithm. I can add some code when I have time.

Comment: The google words for this technique are "breadth first search", or BFS.

Comment: @MattTimmermans What I suggested was a top down dynamic programming approach (so that we can take profit of already evaluated solutions to get other solutions faster). It's more like an optimized depth first search (DFS). A simple breadth first search (BFS) would take too much time.

Comment: You didn't actually specify a search order, but the poster wants to find the *shortest* path, so it has to be breadth-first.

Comment: @MattTimmermans What I'm proposing is to do it depth-first but take the minimum of all children solution when you arrive at the root. This way you can take profit of overlapping sub problems (that is what I meant when I used the term dynamic programming in my explanation). But it's true that I can describe it a bit better. I will try to add some images when I have time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans It's actually a classical dilemma in game theory. Here you have a game with only one initial state and only one final state. You can either (DFS + DP + some pruning strategy) or (BFS + some pruning strategy). Which is better will depend on the pruning strategy. But it's difficult to determine it theoretically. The OP needs to try both and check the performance.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Actually there is plethora of methods for solving these kind of games in the literature: randomized trees, reinforcement learning etc. What we are proposing are the oldest existent methods. I suggest the OP to google more the literature for these kind of games if he wants something faster.